# Not able get able to get correct tuple of tuple format to pass into for loop iteration in Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, loops

I want to pass parameters to an API and get results

**Sample Data**

```
df_results.Unique_Coords
    0   51.213:4.386
    1   41.294:36.342
    2   -7.203:112.733
```

The parmaeter should be in format

**Param Format( expected Format)**

```
(('coords', '44.164:28.641'),
 ('fromDate', '2019-12-03'),
 ('toDate', '2019-11-26'))
```

Response

```
response = requests.post('https://example.com/geocoder/geocode', headers=headers, params=d_, ,timeout=(3.05, 27))
```

I am trying to pass values into the API iteratievely.

fromDate = today_date

toDate =shifted_date

**My code till now**

```
today_date =date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
shifted_date = date.today() + timedelta(days=7)
shifted_date =shifted_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

for i, row in df_results.iterrows():
    d_ = '( \'coords\' , \'{0}\' )'.format(str(row["Unique_Coords"]))
```

How to get the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for tuple of tuples, not string with `()`

```
today_date = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
shifted_date = date.today() + timedelta(days=7)
shifted_date = shifted_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

data = [(('coords', str(row["Unique_Coords"])), ('fromDate', today_date), ('toDate', shifted_date)) for i, row in df_results.iterrows()]
```

This will produce a list of tuple of tuples

```
(('coords', '51.213:4.386'), ('fromDate', '2019-11-26'), ('toDate', '2019-12-03'))
(('coords', '41.294:36.342'), ('fromDate', '2019-11-26'), ('toDate', '2019-12-03'))
(('coords', '-7.203:112.733'), ('fromDate', '2019-11-26'), ('toDate', '2019-12-03'))
```

Comment: Getting an error ` tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: @snehanair Try `for i, row in df_results.iterrows()` instead of `for row in df_results.iterrows()`